# EASY! But which conditional statement works

Tags: php, if-statement

Simple but this has always bothered me. Which is the best way to condition statement?

```
$foo = '1';

if($foo === '1' || $foo === '2' || $foo === '3')
{
// foo matches 
}

or 

if($foo === '1' || '2' || '3')
{
// foo matches
}
```

Which step works and is better. is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second version will always evaluate to true.

If you want to compact the comparison against multiple alternatives then use:

```
if (in_array($foo, array('1', '2', '3') )) {
```

If you want to closely match the exact comparison `===` then you would however need:

```
if (is_string($foo) && in_array($foo, array(...))) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$foo = 1;

if(in_array($foo, array(1, 2, 3))){
    //foo matches 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative:

```
if($foo>0 && $foo<4){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Second if statement won't work.  PHP doesn't work like that. Any number other than 0 (including negatives) evaluates to true when alone in an if statement.  This is why you can do something like `if(count($array))` without specifying that `count($array)` must be greater than 0.

Would be the same as if you had said:

```
if($foo === 1)
{}
elseif(2)  //This will always trigger if $foo !== 1.  
{}
elseif(3)  //This will never trigger because of the last one
{}
```

Each condition is it's own self contained condition.  Instead of reading it as just "or" or "and" read it as "or if" and "and if".  So `if $foo is 1 or if 2 or if 3` instead of `if $foo is 1 or 2 or 3`

If it's just numeric, then amosrivera's solution is the best.  If it's for other types of data, then webarto/mario have a good solution.